# How to use a site to work on localhost with the help of node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am learning node.js where i am trying to use Google webpage to work on my localhost where its menu items to be removed but its search functionality should work on localhost as it works on website. This I tried working to use google on localhost but on localhost it shows "Can not Get", is this a kind of error or am i doing wrong please guide me that how i can achieve what i want to work. I am using node.js ver5.9.1 on XP.

Thanks in advance.

**search.js**

```
var express = require('express'),   
        app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
   compression = require('compression');   
var NLTunnel = require('node-local-tunnel');        
   var options = {

  remoteHost : 'http://www.google.com/',
  localBase : 'http://localhost:3000'
};
   NLTunnel.client(options);    

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(compression());
app.use(express.static('assets/'));

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: have you started the app by running `node search.js` (in the project directory) ?

Comment: Yes, I started the app by running **node search.js**  in the project directory.....

Answer (score 0):

```
    var express = require('express'),   
       app = express(),
       bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
       compression = require('compression'),
       http = require('http'),
       server = http.createServer(app);

    app.use(bodyParser());   
    app.use('/', express.static('public'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
    app.use(compression());

    server.listen(3000);
```

Try this. This is working on my machine.

Comment: Still getting the same on terminal **Cannot GET /**

Comment: In your code there is     **vNLTunnel = require('node-local-tunnel');**      **NLTunnel.client(options);**      its is throwing error else after rempving v NLTunnel it is giving same thing on terminal **Cannot GET /**

Comment: @ansh oh sorry i forget one thing i changed in my code

Comment: No @avinash still it is showing same thing **Cannot GET /**

Comment: remove this line ` app.use(express.static('assets/')); `

Comment: **body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json/urlencoded middlewares searc.js:109:13
body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option node_modules\
body-parser\index.js:105:29**
In command prompt now your code gives this above message too and on terminal same thing **Cannot GET /**

Comment: What did you change? Why should it make a difference? Please don't write answers that are expressed in the form of a game of spot-the-difference!

Comment: If we remove this two lines  **remoteHost : 'http://www.google.com/',
      localBase : 'http://localhost:3000'**  how the app will come to know that which webpage has to use on localhost???

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using **request** and **cheerio** but i am getting only html page and no any **css** or **js** page (if there) and search function is also not working. Is this right to work on and how we can make search functionality to work as usual on localhost.

```
var httpobj = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var all_html;
var url = 'https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=dVHeVuLuG-uK8QeCk6vICw'

request(url, function (error, response, html) {
var $page = cheerio.load(html);
all_html = $page("html");    
}); 


httpobj.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});          
res.write(all_html + ' '); 
res.end('');
}).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```